# File tailing difference between Python 2 and 3?

Tags: python

I've created a class that periodically reads from the end of a file. I've noticed that in python2, it's necessary to seek to the end of the file if read returns no data (we're already at the end of the file). But in python3 this is not necessary. I discovered the seeking implementation here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/157035/

The seek causes both python2 and python3 to work as expected, but I'm curious what changed between the two versions that causes this difference. It doesn't seem to be documented in the usual python2->3 references, but maybe I'm missing something.

**This program reproduces the behavior:**

```
import sys
import threading
import time

class FileTailer(object):
    def __init__(self, path, on_read_fn, binary=False):
        self._path = path
        mode = 'r'
        if binary:
            mode = 'rb'
        self._file = open(path, mode)
        self._on_read_fn = on_read_fn
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self._thread_body)
        self._thread.daemon = True
        self._thread.start()

    def _thread_body(self):
        while True:
            where = self._file.tell()
            data = self._file.read(1024)
            if not data:
                time.sleep(1)
                if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'seek':
                    self._file.seek(where)
            else:
                self._on_read_fn(data)

f = open('a.txt', 'w')

time.sleep(1)

def on_read(data):
    sys.stdout.write('Read: %s' % data)


ft = FileTailer('a.txt', on_read)

for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(3)
    data = 'somedata %s\n' % i
    sys.stdout.write('Writing: %s' % data)
    f.write(data)
    f.flush()

time.sleep(2)
print('Done')
```

**Outputs with seek turned on and off for Python 3.0.1 and Python 2.7.12:**

```
$ PYENV_VERSION=3.0.1 python tail_test.py seek
Writing: somedata 0
Read: somedata 0
Writing: somedata 1
Read: somedata 1
Writing: somedata 2
Read: somedata 2
Done

$ PYENV_VERSION=3.0.1 python tail_test.py
Writing: somedata 0
Read: somedata 0
Writing: somedata 1
Read: somedata 1
Writing: somedata 2
Read: somedata 2
Done

$ PYENV_VERSION=2.7.12 python tail_test.py seek
Writing: somedata 0
Read: somedata 0
Writing: somedata 1
Read: somedata 1
Writing: somedata 2
Read: somedata 2
Done

$ PYENV_VERSION=2.7.12 python tail_test.py
Writing: somedata 0
Writing: somedata 1
Writing: somedata 2
Done
```

Comment: Note that in python2, `mode='r'` is the same as `mode='rb'` using the builtin `open` - you should always use `io.open` instead.

Comment: It's probably nothing but a fluke side-effect of the changes from Python 2 and 3...and doesn't really matter much because seeking works in both. At any rate for text files—which are usually the subject ot `tail`-type processing—you really only need to do a single `self._file.seek(0, os.Seek_END) at the beginning of the `_thread_body()` method before entering the `while True:` loop _if_ you as change the loop to `data = self._file.readline()`, `if not data:`, `time.sleep(0.1)` because the `readline()` will leave the file positioned at its updated end.